# trying to upload file to server, but php script not getting file details

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to upload an image to a server, then get that image name and insert it into mysql database.  Before I got to the database bit, the upload isn't working.  I have narrowed it down to the fact there is no data in the $_FILES array, when I echo out $imageFileName is it blank.

Here is part of my form:

```
<form name="addItem" method="post" action="add-new-item.php">   
    <input name="name" placeholder="Portfolio Item Name" type="text" id="itemName"/><br />
    <input type="file" name="imageName" id="imageName" /><br />

</form>
```

Script, which is part of the same page the form is on:

```
   $target = "images/";
   $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['imageName']['name']);        
   $imageFileName=($_FILES['imageName']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imageName']['tmp_name'], $target)){

          echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
    }else {
          echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
    }

 $query1="INSERT INTO portfolio_items (item_name,full_size_image)  VALUES('$itemName','$itemImage')";
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to include the following in your `<form>` tag :

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

So it would become :

```
<form name="addItem" method="post" action="add-new-item.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

[Documented very well here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) - see the note at the bottom of the first page ...

Comment: @Nicola no probs ... no doubt one day you will be answering this type of question with the same answer ...

Comment: does there need to be an open database connection for it to work?

Comment: @Nicola to upload a file no ... but to run a query against a database yes ... see [mysql examples here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php)